# using jquery to set value of a select box

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the value of a select box using jquery.Here's the code I have:

```
$(function() {
     $("#contact_types").val($("#contact_type_description").val());
});
```

I don't get any error messages but the value of the select box is not set correctly.
When I debug in the console in Chrome, this is what I get:

```
> $("#contact_type_description").val()
> "Office"


> $("#contact_types").html()
> "<option value="6">Home</option><option value="4">Mobile</option><option value="5">Office</option>"
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The value of the option with the text "Office" is 5, not "Office".

Comment: Do you mean the initial value of the select box?

Comment: Grim, as soon as I finshed submitting this post, I saw my bug.  You're right! if you want to post as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You do know that you need to use the `@` sign so @Grim will get notified right?

Comment: @dot - just accept one of the other correct answers, I'm not fussy about numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<option>` with the **value** office, this is what `val` is looking for, the value, not the innerHTML.

You can use this:

```
var theValue = $("#contact_type_description").val();
$('#contact_types option').filer(function(){
    return this.innerHTML === theValue;
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the select option's selected property to true, this should probably be in some control's change or keypress event handler:

```
$('#contacttypes option').each(function(){
   if($(this).text() == SOME_VALUE_YOU_GET_FROM_SOMEWHERE)
    $(this).prop('selected', true);    
});
```

Comment: Ohh, and it should have been `2` as `eq` uses the zero base index.